# Why doesn't css before work even with full content?

Tags: html, css

I need to make some blue circles before every string of list. But instead I got only indents.

```css
.list li:before{
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;

}
```

```html
    <ul class="list">
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Those dots aren't created using a border, and you aren't adding a border. Add `border: 1px solid;` to your style to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `border-style` is `none`.

You've given you elements a `border-color` and a `border-radius`, but you haven't changed `border-style` so there's nothing to see.

```css
.list li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing you're doing now is this:

```css
.list li:before{
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid; /* you forgot to add this */
    border-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

You're creating new bullets, you're not styling the default ones.

what you want to do is this:

```css
.list li::marker {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1rem;
    content: '+ '; /* put whatever you want with a space */
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

There you go :)

EDIT: You can also replace it with images. [check w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp)